# Meteor: Subscription doesn't work

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to get a document from the server and display it on the client but the subscription always return a collection with no document.

```
// server/publications.js
Meteor.publish('myPages', function() {
    return Pages.findOne({userId: this.userId});
});

// collection/pages.js
MyPages = new Meteor.Collection('myPages');

// client/main.js
Meteor.subscribe('myPages');

// client/view.js
Template.myView.helpers({
    myPages: function(e, t) {
        console.debug(MyPages.find({}));
        return MyPages.find({});
    }
});
```

Comment: Is the user logged in?  `this.userId` will be `null` if the user isn't logged in, which is probably not what you want.  Also, is using `Pages` in `Meteor.publish` vs `MyPages` in `Template.myView.helpers` intentional?  Where is `MyPages` defined?

Comment: My user is logged in. Yes it is intentional, because I want the client to only get his pages. Is it the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot move a document between collections via a subscription. If you subscribe to get a document that's in `Pages` collection, defined as `new Meteor.Collection("pages")`, then no matter how your pubsub channels look like, on the client the document will be found in the collection defined as `new Meteor.Collection("pages")`. So remove all traces of `MyPages` and use `Pages` on the client as well. You'll find the document there.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use findOne to publish collections: it doesn't return a cursor but an actual object.

Does this not work?

```
Meteor.publish('myPages', function() {
    return Pages.find({userId: this.userId});
});
```

or, if necessary:

```
Meteor.publish('myPages', function() {
    return Pages.find({userId: this.userId}, {limit: 1});
});
```

Comment: It still returns an empty collection. And I know that the Pages collection is not empty since it returns documents from the console (Pages.find({})) with autopublish enabled.

Comment: Pages or MyPages? You seem to be mixing both. What is Pages?

Comment: Pages is the whole collection of every pages (from every users). In this collection I'm trying to return the pages for the logged user (he doesn't need to get the pages of other users). That's what MyPages is. The pages of this user. Is it the proper way to do it?